# PHP Zend export google docs with 401 Unauthorized error message

Tags: php, zend-framework, export-to-excel, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am running a problem with exporting a Google Docs (spreasheet) to xls file and save to our own server.

After successfully uploaded a file to Google Docs but somehow getting the 401 error message when I do the download.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 401
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is our PHP code and hope someone could help me to point out what went wrong.

Any thoughts would be highly received.

```
<?php

// set credentials for ClientLogin authentication
$google_user = 'xxxxx'; // Your google account username
$google_pass = 'xxxxx'; // Your google account password

$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME; 
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($google_user, $google_pass,$service);
$docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($httpClient);

// Uploading file to Google Docs works perfectly as below
//$newDocumentEntry = $docs->uploadFile('test.txt', 'order-123456','text/plain', Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI);


$path = "/var/www/vhosts/googledocs";


$docsQuery = new Zend_Gdata_Docs_Query();
$docsQuery->setTitle("My Spreadsheet Name");
$docsQuery->setTitleExact(false);
$feed = $docs->getDocumentListFeed($docsQuery);

foreach ($feed->entries as $entry) {
    $docID = $entry->getId();
    $docTitle = $entry->getTitle();  


    if($entry->getTitle() == "My spreadsheet File Name"){
        $strURL = $entry->content->getSrc() . '&exportFormat=xls&format=xls';            
        $data = $docs->get($strURL);
        file_put_contents($path."test.xls", $data);
    }
}


?>
```

UPDATE - 23/05/2012

We finally got it working by tweaking the code as below: It would be useful for someone !

```
foreach($feed as $entry): 
        if($entry->getTitle() == 'My Spreadsheet File Name'){
            $path = "/var/www/vhosts/regustouchstone.com/subdomains/docs/httpdocs/googledocs";
            $strURL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=".basename($entry->id)."&exportFormat=xls&format=xls";

            try{            
                $data = $service->get($strURL)->getBody();              
                $fp = fopen($path."/test.xls", "w+");
                                fwrite($fp, $data);
                                fclose($fp);                
            }catch(Zend_Exception $e) {
                echo "<br /><br /> ERROR <br />";
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a solution as below:

```
foreach($feed as $entry): 
        if($entry->getTitle() == 'My Spreadsheet File Name'){
            $path = "/var/www/vhosts/regustouchstone.com/subdomains/docs/httpdocs/googledocs";
            $strURL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=".basename($entry->id)."&exportFormat=xls&format=xls";

            try{            
                $data = $service->get($strURL)->getBody();              
                $fp = fopen($path."/test.xls", "w+");
                                fwrite($fp, $data);
                                fclose($fp);                
            }catch(Zend_Exception $e) {
                echo "<br /><br /> ERROR <br />";
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is $strUrl correctly and consistently encoded, e.g. are all '&' being encoded as '&'?

Also, if the server for the download link is http://spreadsheets.google.com (as opposed to http://docs.google.com) you might need to authenticate to the Spreadsheet service:

```
$spreadsheetClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($google_user, $google_pass, Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
$spreadSheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($spreadsheetClient);
...
// download the spreadsheet
$data = $spreadSheetService->get($strURL);
```

Comment: Hi Claudio, thank you very much for your input. The $strUL has value as [view link here](https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0ArlTr8ic6sQ7dExMUl9taHo4QmYwa0ZyanVvQWZWOGc&exportFormat=xls&format=xls) . I will give it a go with spreedsheet authenticate and get back to you if there is any progress.

Comment: I am getting close.. The 401 error message is gone once started using $spreadSheetService and encode the URL. However, new error message returned `Invalid scheme: 'http%3a%2f%2fspreadsheets.google.com%2ffeeds%2fdownload%2fspreadsheets%2fexport%3fkey%3d0arltr8ic6sq7dexmul9taho4qmywa0zyanvvqwzwogc%26exportformat%3dxls%26format%3dxls'`

Comment: URL has been encoded by PHP function as `$strURL = urlencode('http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=').'0ArlTr8ic6sQ7dExMUl9taHo4QmYwa0ZyanVvQWZWOGc'.urlencode ('&exportFormat=xls&format=xls');`